# How to show simple inequality of fractions

Tags: inequality, fractions

If $$\frac {a}{a+b}<\frac{a'}{a'+b'}$$ then how can I show that $$\frac {a}{a+2b}<\frac{a'}{a'+2b'}\ \forall\ a,b,c>0$$

I tried puitting in a constant k so  $$\frac {a}{a+b}=k*\frac{a}{a+2b}$$ and I get $$k=\frac{a+b}{a+2b}$$ and I dont know where from there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to require that at least $b$ and $b'$ must be positive.

Comment: I apologize. Yes a and b are also positive

Comment: I donot think it is always true

Comment: arrggg. sorry changed it once more to a+b in the denominator

Comment: You have to require that a/b>1, right?

Comment: You shouldn't keep changing your question each time someone responds.  Where did you come across this question and what are your thoughts on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume everything is positive.

If
$\frac {a}{a+b}<\frac{a'}{a'+b'}$,
then
$a(a'+b') < a'(a+b)$.

We want to know when
$\frac {a}{a+2b}<\frac{a'}{a'+2b'}$
or
$a(a'+2b') < a'(a+2b)$.

Let
$u = a'(a+b)-a(a'+b') > 0$
and
$v = a'(a+2b)-a(a'+2b')$.
We want to when
$v > 0$.

Since
$u = a'b-ab' > 0$,
$a'b > ab'$.

We have
$v 
= (a'(a+b)+a'b)-(a(a'+b')+ab')
=  a'(a+b)-a(a'+b')+a'b-ab'
=  u+a'b-ab'
$.

Since,
as shown above,
$a'b > ab'$
and
$u > 0$,
then
$v > 0$
as we wanted to show.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it isn't true even for all numbers positive.

$$ \frac{30}{6}< \frac{6}{1} $$

but

$$ \frac{130}{106}> \frac{106}{101} $$

Comment: Am I supposed to delete my answer now that the question has changed ?

Comment: you got upvotes, just leave it. it was my bust, I thought I could simplify the problem

Answer (score 1):

I can show that the relation is not general. Define a function $f(x)=(a+x)(b'+x)-(a'+x)(b+x)=ab'-a'b+(a+b'-a'-b)x$.

By the assumption (all numbers are positive), $f(0)=ab'-a'b>0$. But, under the assumption, we cannot determine the slope of $f(x)$:

slope $=a+b'-a'-b$.

Therefore, this relation is not a general one.

Comment: I'm trying to see how that relates to the answer that marty gave I'm assuming but I can't see how they are the same.

Comment: First, althougt you edited your question many times, the relation $a/b<a'/b'$ still holds. So you attempt to prove $(a+c)/(b+c)<(a'+c)/(b'+c)$. Multiply both sides by $(b+c)(b'+c)$ and then move all terms to one side of the inequality, you have $(a+c)(b'+c)-(a'+c)(b+c)<0$. Now, replace $c$ by$x$ then you get the function $f(x)$. So you want to show $f(x)<0$ when $f(0)<0$, which is not generally true. If the slope of $f(x)$ is positive, $f(x)$ will eventually become positive.

Comment: Oh ok I see now thanks